# Editting case statment from another method?

Tags: java, methods, case-statement

For a program i am writing for school one of the extensions says i need to figure a way to to edit a case statement if i enter as an admin, I have created two methods because it seemed like the best way to do this.

method one (the one i need to edit):

```
public static double costSqM(Console c) {
    double price = 0;
    int choice;
    c.println("#. Type               Cost per sq.m.");
    c.println("1. Low pile carpet           $ ");
    c.print(pileCost, 5, 2);
    c.println("2. Shag rug                  $ ");
    c.print(rugCost, 5, 2);
    c.println("3. Parquet                   $ ");
    c.print(parquetCost, 5, 2);
    c.println("4. Linleum                   $ ");
    c.print(leumCost, 5, 2);
    c.println("5. Hardwood                  $ ");
    c.print(hardwoodCost, 5, 2);
    c.println("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice = c.readInt();
    while (choice < 1 && choice > 5) {
        c.println("That is not a valid choice. Please try again!");
        choice = c.readInt();
    }
    switch (choice) {
    case 0:
        admin(c);
    case 1:
        price = 18.75;
    case 2:
        price = 11.05;
    case 3:
        price = 14.35;
    case 4:
        price = 10.40;
    case 5:
        price = 28.15;
    }
    return price;
}
```

method two (the one I'm editing from):

```
public static void admin(Console c) {
    int choice = 0, priceChange = 0;
    cls(c);
    c.println("Hello admin. What changes would you like to make?");
    c.println("1. Change a price.");
    c.println("2. Add an item.");
    c.println("3. Remove an item.");
    switch(choice){
    //Changing the price of an item
    case 1: 
        c.print("What price would you like to change? ");
        c.println("1. Low Pile Carpet.");
        c.println("2. Shag Rug.");
        c.println("3. Parquet.");
        c.println("4. Linleum.");
        c.println("5. Hardwood.");
        switch(priceChange){
        case 1:
            c.println("Please enter the new price for the Low Pile Carpet: ");
            pileCost = c.readInt();
        case 2:
            c.println("Please enter the new price for the Shag Rug: ");
            rugCost = c.readInt();
        case 3:
            c.println("Please enter the new price for the Parquet: ");
            parquetCost = c.readInt();
        case 4:
            c.println("Please enter the new price for the Linluem: ");
            leumCost = c.readInt();
        case 5:
            c.println("Please enter the new price for the Hardwood: ");
            hardwoodCost = c.readInt();
        }
    //Adding an item
    case 2:
    //Removing an item
    case 3:

    }
```

If it is not possible to do from another method but it is from the same method please explain that too and i can just make it one big method. Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the language you're using. Is this Java?

Comment: yes sorry first question I've posted here :D

Comment: Please Change the Tag for the asked question else some one would vote it down.

Comment: I'm not sure what tag you are talking about, its in java about methods and case statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag for the admin mode. set it to true and you're in admin mode:
`boolean admin = true`.

Then you could simply check if `admin` is `true` and if that is the case, print admin stuff, if not... print those normal outputs.

Example in case the user typed 1:

```
case 1:
    if(admin)
    {  //admin, change price
        c.println("Please enter the new price for the Low Pile Carpet: ");
        pileCost = c.readInt();
    }
    else
    { //non-admin, set price
        price = 18.75;
    }
break; //important! don't forget the break-keyword
```

If you forget to add `break` at the end of a case-statement all of the following statements (e.g. for 2: 3,4,5..) will run.

That should be an inspiration, you should figure out the rest yourself :)

Oh of course you will end up with only 1 method this way, which is smaller than the two before combined since logic isn't duplicated.

Comment: Thanks! This way makes a lot more sense then the way i was doing it. The only real big problem I'm having though is removing or adding case statementthat the admin would want to add?

Comment: How exactly would you 'add' something by the console itself? If there are keys like 0 which are for admin only, just check if admin=true and if not, do nothing.

Comment: This is what it says in my assignment file "4. Can you think of a way to put the flooring types and costs into a format which will allow the “administrator” of the program to change prices, add and delete items, etc." So i would have to be able too add new flooring type or remove them. Any idea?

Comment: You could put them into a `Map`, key is the name of the item, value would be you price. Then you wouldn't need the case anymore, because you can iterate of the `Map` and change it's values, add and remove them etc. But that's a different approach than you have now.

Comment: Would an array work where i ask for the new flooring type name and another array for the price?

Comment: That wouldn't be the best solution, but if you keep name and price for the same product at the same index, everything will be fine.

Comment: Since you're new to SO, please mark this answer as accepted if your question is answered so others will see. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok i will but where do i do that i can't seem to find it?